# XmlSerializer ignore public fields?

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

I am using some existing code that is defined as follows.

```
class Example
{
    public float x_field;
    public float x_property
    {
        get { return x_field; }
        set { x_field = value; }
    }
}
```

Why its defined like this I don't know, but I'm unable to change its implementation. The problem, is that when I serialize it, I obviously get both values in the xml output. How can I stop this from occurring if I can't modify the 'Example' class?

I want the Serializer to only output public properties and not public fields.

Comment: Why would both of these be public?  That's pretty terrible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [XmlAttributeOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides.aspx) parameter of [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfaxz1a0.aspx) e.g.

```
XmlAttributeOverrides overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
XmlAttributes attributes = new XmlAttributes();
attributes.XmlIgnore = true;
overrides.Add(typeof(Example), "x_field", attributes);

XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Example), overrides);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use an intermediate object. One that you can control to create the exact model you want to serialize.

```
class IntermdeiateModel
{
     public float x+property {get;set;}
}
....

return Serializer.Serialze(GetAllEamples().Select(e => new IntermdeiateModel { x_property = e.x_property));
```